# CDI injection fails when two copies of implementation exists

Tags: java, dependency-injection, cdi, weld

I've following issue. For some reasons I have a copy of some jar in two different WAR modules inside one EAR. Unfortunately introducing injection via CDI fails because classloader detects two implementations and it doesn't know which one should be used. There's an error which is something like this :

```
    07:28:35,411 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 215) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./webadm: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./webadm: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException: UT010013: Could not instantiate com.adminconsole.SessionObserver
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:85)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException: UT010013: Could not instantiate com.wincor.adminconsole.session.SessionObserver
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:231)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:100)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:82)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: UT010013: Could not instantiate com.adminconsole.SessionObserver
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedListener.start(ManagedListener.java:50)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.start(ApplicationListeners.java:159)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:173)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYEE0042: Failed to construct component instance
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.constructComponentInstance(BasicComponent.java:163)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.constructComponentInstance(BasicComponent.java:134)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.createInstance(BasicComponent.java:88)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ComponentRegistry$ComponentManagedReferenceFactory.getReference(ComponentRegistry.java:149)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$6.createInstance(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1372)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedListener.start(ManagedListener.java:48)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set com.adminconsole.jsf.context.OcmInitFacesContextFactory field com.adminconsole.SessionObserver.contextFactory to com.adminconsole.jsf.context.OcmInitFacesContextFactory$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy
        at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
        at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)
        at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:81)
        at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:764)
        at org.jboss.weld.injection.FieldInjectionPoint.inject(FieldInjectionPoint.java:94)
        at org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectBoundFields(Beans.java:363)
        at org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectFieldsAndInitializers(Beans.java:374)
        at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultInjector$1.proceed(DefaultInjector.java:71)
        at org.jboss.weld.injection.InjectionContextImpl.run(InjectionContextImpl.java:48)
        at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultInjector.inject(DefaultInjector.java:73)
        at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BasicInjectionTarget.inject(BasicInjectionTarget.java:121)
        at org.jboss.as.weld.injection.WeldInjectionContext.inject(WeldInjectionContext.java:39)
        at org.jboss.as.weld.injection.WeldInjectionInterceptor.processInvocation(WeldInjectionInterceptor.java:51)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.AroundConstructInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(AroundConstructInterceptorFactory.java:28)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
        at org.jboss.as.weld.injection.WeldInterceptorInjectionInterceptor.processInvocation(WeldInterceptorInjectionInterceptor.java:56)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
        at org.jboss.as.weld.injection.WeldInjectionContextInterceptor.processInvocation(WeldInjectionContextInterceptor.java:43)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
        at org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:64)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:356)
        at org.jboss.invocation.PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.processInvocation(PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.java:80)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
        at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.constructComponentInstance(BasicComponent.java:161)
        ... 15 more
```

OcmInitFacesContextFactory is injected into SessionObserver via @Inject annotation

It's sure that it's caused by duplication, because without that copied jar it works fine.

No my question is, is there any way to tell CDI (Weld) to search for dependency only in one WAR module ? I was trying to exclude it for scan (in beans.xml in one of this jar files) but it's not the point as it then won't inject them at all.  Currently I can't change design of this EAR and WAR files.

Comment: Are you using JBoss? If so, see [modules](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/MODULES/Introduction?_sscc=t).

Comment: Yes main main app server is JBoss, however i would need to be able to deploy the same application on WAS

Comment: Post entire stack traces.

Comment: This behaviour is basically per EE spec and from what I know, there is no *portable* way around it unless you change deployment structure. For JBoss, however, there was an option using something like `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` which *may or may not* help you. Try looking that way. But as I said, that won't be portable so you won't make it work on WAS.

Comment: Glassifsh has a work around, where by you delegate the classloading to the earclassloader, and just have a provided scope to the war dependencies. For jboss/wildfly, you will be better of using module loading, which will mitigate the issue of conflict classloaders, as the module classloader will take care of the conflict